# Difference between String str="" and String str = " "

Tags: java

What is the differences between `String str1=""` and `String str2 =" "`? When we print length of str1 there is output 0 and when we print length of str2 output is 1.I want to return a string values based upon some caluclation and if calulated values not exists(due to wrong input) then what should i return from my method? A null values or something else?

Comment: By "there is no output" do you mean it outputs "0"? Because it has to print some length...

Comment: What else are you expecting?

Answer (score 7):

str2 contains a space (length is 1)
str1 is an empty string (length is 0)

Answer (score 1):

str2 contains a space,str1 contains nothing.
`str2.length() = 1`, `str1.empty() = true`

```
"a" + str2 + "word" = "a word"

"a" + str1 + "word" = "aword"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1.empty() == true
str2.empty() == false
```

that's because the str2 contain a space character.